# React's behaviour when pass through props are named the same as other props

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have the following in React:

```js
const Component = () => {
  const props = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 };

  return <AnotherComponent {...props} one="1" />;
}
```

1. What value would prop `one` have when received by `AnotherComponent`?
2. Does the order of pass through props vs other props matter?

I have a bug that I think is being caused by this and I could not find a resource that covers this edge case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `one` would be the string `"1"`.

Yes, the order matters. Later props override earlier props with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```js
return <AnotherComponent {...{...props, one: 1}} />;
```